# Converting hash to string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Let's say we have a hash:

```
flash = {}
flash[:error] = "This is an error."
flash[:info] = "This is an information."
```

I would like to convert it to a string:

```
"<div class='error'>This is an error.</div><div class='info'>This is an information".
```

in nice one liner ;)

I found something like that:

```
flash.to_a.collect{|item| "<div class='#{item[0]}'>#{item[1]}</div>"}.join
```

That solves my problem but maybe there is nicer solution built in hashtable class?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) includes [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), so you can use [`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003158):

```
flash.collect { |k, v| "<div class='#{k}'>#{v}</div>" }.join
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys in the hash using

```
flash.keys
```

and then from there you can build a new array of strings and then join them.  So something like

```
flash.keys.collect {|k| "<div class=#{k}>#{flash[k]}</div>"}.join('')
```

Does that do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

`inject` is infinitely handy:

```
flash.inject("") { |acc, kv| acc << "<div class='#{kv[0]}'>#{kv[1]}</div>" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[:info, :error].collect { |k| "<div class=\"#{k}\">#{flash[k]}</div>" }.join
```

The only problem with solutions presented so far is that you usually need to list flash messages in particular order - and hash doesn't have it, so IMHO it's better use pre-defined array.

Comment: You can also use Ruby 1.9, or borrow ActiveSupport's `OrderedHash` if you require Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Or maby?

```
class Hash
  def do_sexy
    collect { |k, v| "<div class='#{k}'>#{v}</div>" }.flatten
  end
end

flash = {}
flash[:error] = "This is an error."
flash[:info] = "This is an information."

puts flash.do_sexy

#outputs below
<div class='error'>This is an error.</div>
<div class='info'>This is an information.</div>
```