# Convert Ruby Hash into YAML

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I need to convert a hash like the one provided below into readable YAML. It looks like I can feed `YAML::load` a string, but I think I need to convert it first into something like this:

```
hostname1.test.com:
  public: 51
  private: 10

{"hostname1.test.com"=>
   {"public"=>"51", "private"=>"10"},
 "hostname2.test.com"=>
   {"public"=>"192", "private"=>"12"}
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how to do that conversion into that string effectively though.

I looked through the HASH documentation and couldn't find anything for `to_yaml`. I found it by searching for `to_yaml` which becomes available when you `require yaml`. I also tried to use the Enumerable method `collect` but got confused when I needed to iterate through the value (another hash).

I'm trying to use "[Converting hash to string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038275/converting-hash-to-string-in-ruby)" as a reference. My thought was then to feed that into `YAML::load` and that would generate the YAML I wanted.

Comment: Did you read through Ruby's [YAML documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html)? How about "[Yaml Cookbook at the YamlForRuby site](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html)? Also, your supplied hash isn't valid. Should it be an array of hashes, or a hash of hashes?

Comment: You also should have supplied code showing what you've tried, along with an explanation of what didn't work. -1 for not showing any effort.

Comment: Added the work that I did prior to finding the to_yaml method.

Comment: `to_yaml` is not part of Hash or Object or any class by default. You *HAVE* to `require 'yaml'` someplace in the script, or in something you require, for YAML to extend Object, Hash, and other methods. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'yaml'

HASH_OF_HASHES = {
  "hostname1.test.com"=> {"public"=>"51", "private"=>"10"},
  "hostname2.test.com"=> {"public"=>"192", "private"=>"12"}
}

ARRAY_OF_HASHES = [
  {"hostname1.test.com"=> {"public"=>"51", "private"=>"10"}},
  {"hostname2.test.com"=> {"public"=>"192", "private"=>"12"}}
]

puts HASH_OF_HASHES.to_yaml
puts
puts ARRAY_OF_HASHES.to_yaml
```

Which outputs:

```
---
hostname1.test.com:
  public: '51'
  private: '10'
hostname2.test.com:
  public: '192'
  private: '12'

---
- hostname1.test.com:
    public: '51'
    private: '10'
- hostname2.test.com:
    public: '192'
    private: '12'
```

---

> The Object class has a to_yaml method. I used that and it generated the YAML file correctly.

No, it doesn't.

This is from a freshly opened IRB session:

```
Object.instance_methods.grep(/to_yaml/)
=> []
require 'yaml'
=> true
Object.instance_methods.grep(/to_yaml/)
=> [:psych_to_yaml, :to_yaml, :to_yaml_properties]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `to_yaml` method on a hash for this I believe after you `require yaml`

Comment: Hash doesn't have a `to_yaml` method.

Comment: [Object does *not* have a `to_yaml` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html). Only the [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) class has it, and it extends other classes when it's required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`YAML.dump`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html):

```rb
YAML.dump(a: 2, b: 1)
=> "---\n:a: 2\n:b: 1\n
```

One advantage of `YAML.dump` over `to_yaml` is that it's easier to infer what the code is doing because most people read from left to right.