# Resque scheduler pass hash argument to Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I have a job that receives a hash argument in its `perform` method. I want to call it periodically. I defined a CRON to schedule it on the `resque_schedule.yml` file. I am trying this way:

```
UpdateInterestHistoryJob:
  cron: "0 0 * * * America/Sao_Paulo"
  args:
    classifier: :SIAPE
```

However, inside the job, I get the arguments as an array:

```
["classifier", "SIAPE"]
```

How do I define it correctly? How do I define the job argument as a hash on the `yml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested here and a simple dash should be enough:

```
UpdateInterestHistoryJob:
  cron: "* * * * * America/Sao_Paulo"
  args:
    - classifier: :SIAPE
```

Also, should you need more arguments in your Resque job, simply place them without further dashes:

```
UpdateInterestHistoryJob:
  cron: "* * * * * America/Sao_Paulo"
  args:
    - classifier: :SIAPE
      another: value
```

Answer (score 1):

between your `Hash` and the one included [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034072/hash-inside-yaml-file#3034093) from [Ceilingfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58991/ceilingfish) I see discrepancy:

> You can mark it up like this

```
feeds:
 - 
  url: 'http://www.google.com'
  label: 'default'
```

> Note **the spacing is important here. "-" must be indented by a single space (not a tab), and followed by a single space. And url & label must be indented by two spaces (not tabs either).**
>
> Additionally this might be helpful: http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html

This is from ww.yaml.org

> **Simple Inline Hash**
>   Mapping can also be contained on a single line, using the inline syntax. Each key-value pair is separated by a colon, with a comma between each entry in the mapping. Enclose with curly braces.
>   Yaml
>
> Simple Inline Hash          in YAML?

```
hash: { name: Steve, foo: bar }
```

> Ruby
>
> Simple Inline Hash          in Ruby?

```
{ 'hash' => { 'name' => 'Steve', 'foo' => 'bar' } }
```

I also include [this link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html) from the official YAMLSyntax and there is many explanation about this

[Convert Ruby Hash into YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576472/convert-ruby-hash-into-yaml#17576810)
https://codedump.io/share/w2EriSJ0wO7T/1/convert-ruby-hash-into-yaml